# Rails script access model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

i need a script to be able to access my model. I found a post about this which suggested doing

```
require "#{ENV['RAILS.root']}/config/environment.rb"
```

in the top of my script. then i can run ruby script/my_script.rb to run it. But this gives me the error

```
/Users/my_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- /config/environment.rb (LoadError)
```

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 10):

I think `ENV['RAILS.root']` will be set after the environment is loaded. You can try

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
```

However, a more commonly used idiom is writing Rake task. For example, create a file named `lib/tasks/mytask.rake`:

```
task :mytask => :environment do
  # Do something with your model
end
```

Then execute `rake mytask`. The `environment` task will automatically load the Rails environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. forget what i said to include in the top. put this instead

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
```